# get Length of a Array of Class in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have Node class like this:

```
public class Node {
        public string name;
        public int val;
        public string op;
        public Node left;
        public Node right;

        public Node(string name, int val, string op, Node left, Node right) {
            this.name = name;
            this.val = val;
            this.op = op;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
        public Node() {
            name = null;
            val = 0;
            op = null;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
}
```

and then in Main method i declare it like this:

```
 public static void Main() {
            Node[] arr = new Node[500];
            arr[0] = new Node("asd",0,null,null,null);
            WriteLine(arr.Length);
 }
```

My output is 500 (my expectation is 1) although i declared a new Node to the array . Please help. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 4):

Use a List instead, arrays are fixed length.

```
public static void Main() {
        List<Node> arr = new List<Node>();
        arr.Add(new Node("asd",0,null,null,null));
        WriteLine(arr.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the items that are not null:

```
arr.Count(n => n != null)
```

The `Length` property returns size of the array but it's preinitialized with a fixed size hence the result you see in your code.